# Action completion from UR controller

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, ur10, ur-driver, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the UR controller (CB3/UR10) provide any feedback (such as move complete/acknowledgement ) given trajectory commands from `ur_modern_driver` through ROS or UR script commands directly such as movej?

I read from this link : https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/issues/162

> There's no way to detect whether "the
> script" has finished. That is a
> limitation of the infrastructure
> provided by UR, not of the driver btw

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285345/action-completion-from-ur-controller/) by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
May I suggest a title change? Your question is about feedback, but when talking about robots and controllers, most people will understand this as meaning position or velocity feedback. Your question is really more about control flow synchronisation and action completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quoting myself in #q285090:

> The `ur_modern_driver` exposes a [FollowJointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html) action server. As the name implies, that server accepts goals containing a [JointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html).

Interacting with an action server is done by writing an action client. This interaction can be both synchronous (ie: blocking) and asynchronous (ie: non-blocking). The former only returns when a trajectory has completed, the latter returns immediately.

I'd suggest you review the [wiki/actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) documentation and do some of the tutorials. That should provide you with some insight.

---

Edit: note that `ur_modern_driver` does not directly use URScript when executing a trajectory. The limitations mentioned by Thomas only apply when sending script snippets to the controller over the `/urscript` topic.

---

Edit2: see also the [test_move.py](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/blob/9397f47ac158fe5976719f33101334371bc15d44/test_move.py) Python script that implements a very rudimentary action client to control the robot through the driver.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
Finally: please realise that using Actions to interact with robot drivers is not specific to `ur_modern_driver` at all. It's a fundamental piece of infrastructure in ROS. Getting good understanding of Actions is paramount if you want to create a serious application with ROS.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-14**:
I understand regarding the ROS part. In case, I'd like to publish script commands over `/urscript` topic, the UR controller provides no feedback regarding action completion? Am I correct?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
Yes. That is exactly as Thomas explained it in the issue you linked to. A work-around that has been suggested is to use controller digital IOs as flags to signal completion of script snippets sent to `/urscript` and then monitor those from ROS.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-14**:
Perfect thanks!
Also, the UR controller will crash if I try to send trajectory commands through the action server and simultaneously send script commands through `/urscript` topic, correct?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
I don't recall it "crashing", but it is definitely not supported no.

Is this something you have experienced, or concluded from something you've read somewhere?

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-14**:
@gvdhoorn, It doesn't crash but if I run the `test_move.py` and publish `movej` commands to the `/urscript` continuously and simultaneously, the script commands seem to take priority. Ofcourse, I tried this in UR-Sim

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
Sending `movej` statements to `/urscript` seems strange to me. Why do you do that? If you're not going to use the trajectory action server, why use the driver in the first place?

> the script commands seem to take priority

they don't take priority per se, but the ctrlr terminates the driver.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-14**:
No this was just a random test. I will use the driver, I was curious if I could also access other UR script functions while using the driver

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
well you can, but not while executing a trajectory.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
You could try and see whether you can send a *secondary program*. Look that up in the UR scripting manual. Secondary programs might not interfere with the driver. You probably cannot control motion that way, but setting IOs could/should work.